# How can I create, delete, update, and read comments in one URL?

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-forms

## How can I create, delete, update, and read comments in one URL?

## What you want to achieve

I want to implement create, update, read, delete in one function of view. I want to implement it without changing the URL.
Now Users can't comment twice in a movie.

## Current code

```
def view_movie_detail(request, movie_id):
    movie, created = Movie.objects.get_or_create(id=movie_id)
# if method is post then the form will populated with posted data  else will be empty form 
    form = Comment_movie_CreateForm(request.POST or None)
# check if user has comment about that movie
    comment_exists = Comment_movie.objects.filter(user=request.user,movie=movie).exists()
    message = ""
    
    if comment_exists:
        # if comment exists return a message to the view html 
        message = "Dear {} you already commented that movie".format(request.user.nickname)
        #return render (request, "Movie/movie_detail.html", context)
    # save the new comment
    elif form.is_valid():
        Comment_movie (
            comment = form.cleaned_data ['comment'],
            user = request.user,
            stars = form.cleaned_data ['stars'],
            movie = movie
        ).save()
        return redirect('view_movie_detail', movie_id = movie_id)
    data = requests.get(f"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{movie_id}?api_key={TMDB_API_KEY}&language=en-US")
    recommendations = requests.get(f"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{movie_id}/recommendations?api_key={TMDB_API_KEY}&language=en-US")
    comments = reversed(Comment_movie.objects.filter (movie_id = movie_id))
    average = movie.average_stars()
    context = {
            "data": data.json(),
            "recommendations": recommendations.json(),
            "type": "movie",
            "comments": comments,
            "average": average,
            "form": form,
            "message": message,
            }
    return render (request, "Movie/movie_detail.html", context)
```

```
class Movie (models.Model):
    id = models.CharField (primary_key = True, editable = False,
                          validators = [alphanumeric], max_length = 9999)
    def get_comments (self):
        return Comment_movie.objects.filter (movie_id = self.id)
    
    def average_stars (self):
        comments = self.get_comments ()
        n_comments = comments.count ()

        if n_comments:
            return sum ([comment.stars for comment in comments]) / n_comments
        else: else:
            return 0
class Comment_movie (models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user','movie',)
    
    comment = models.TextField (max_length = 1000)
    stars = models.FloatField (
                     blank = False,
                     null = False,
                     default = 0,
                     validators = [MinValueValidator (0.0),
                     MaxValueValidator (10.0)]
                  )

    user = models.ForeignKey (CustomUser, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    movie = models.ForeignKey (Movie, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField (default = datetime.now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField (auto_now = True)
```

```
class Comment_movie_CreateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment_movie
        fields = ('comment', 'stars',)
    comment = forms.CharField(required=False,label='comment',max_length=1000)
    stars   = forms.FloatField(required=False,label='stars',widget=forms.TextInput(
       attrs={'type': 'number','id':'form_homework',"class": "no_resize",'min': '0','max':'10','step':'0.1'}))
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        return cleaned_data
    def clean_stars(self):
        stars = self.cleaned_data['stars']
        if stars != None:
            if stars < 0 or stars > 10:
                raise forms.ValidationError("The rating input is incorrect.")
            return stars
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError("The rating input is incorrect.")
    def clean_comment(self):
        comment = self.cleaned_data['comment']
        if len(comment) > 1000:
            raise forms.ValidationError("There are too many characters.")
        elif len(comment) == 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please enter the characters.")
        return comment
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.label_suffix=" "
```

```
{% if user.is_anonymous %}
    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'account_login' %}">Login</a>
    <hr>
    {% else %}
    <h2>Comments</h2>
    {% if message %}
    <h2>{{message}}</h2>
    <hr>
    {% else %}
    {% if form.errors %}
        <div class = "error_list">
            {% for errors in form.errors.values %}
                {% for error in errors %}
                    {{ error }}<br>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
         <button type="submit">Edit Comment</button>
        <button type="submit" name="action" value="delete">Delete Comment</button>
        <button type="submit">Post Comment</button>
         
    </form>
    {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
    <hr>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <tr>
            <th>image</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>created_at</th>
            <th>comment</th>
            <th>evaluation</th>
            </tr>
            {% for c in comments %}
            <tr>
                    <td><img class="rounded-circle" src="{{ user.avatar.url }}" alt="..."width="100" height="100"></td>
                    <td>{{ c.user.nickname }}</td>
                    <td>{{ c.created_at }} </td> 
                    <td>{{ c.comment }}</td>
                    <td><h2 class = "rate" style="--rating:{{c.stars}}">{{c.stars}}</h2></td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
            <hr>
```

## What I asked

How can I make a comment in one URL CRUD?

Comment: one  approach  is to add unique together  in your  model  (user,movie).  Second approarch is to use  django shortcut in model   which is  create_or_update   based on your  criteria  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create

Comment: If you take the second method
Comment_movie (
                 comment = form.cleaned_data ['comment'],
                 user = request.user,
                 stars = form.cleaned_data ['stars'],
                 movie = movie
             ). Save ()
This is Comment_movie.objects.update_or_create (
                 user = request.user,
                 defaults = {
                 comment: form.cleaned_data ['comment'],
                 stars: form.cleaned_data ['stars'],
                 }
                 movie = movie
                 )
Do you change it like this?

Comment: it is the opposite  in the seccond approach  in the defaults  is the data to query from  so you have to pass  the user an the movie  not the comment string   because you want to update or create the comment string  ,  read the docs  about create_or_update

Comment: How should I change the first approach?

Comment: read the django docs  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/options/#unique-together 

also you need to create migration

Comment: unique_together = [['user','movie']] I changed it like this, but I get an error. Isn't this?

Comment: I don't know even if I look at the document, but where and how should I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to add  unique  together in your  model  with indexes for bettter performance you can use smth like this

```
class Comment_movie (models.Model):

comment = models.TextField (max_length = 1000)
stars = models.FloatField (
                 blank = False,
                 null = False,
                 default = 0,
                 validators = [MinValueValidator (0.0),
                 MaxValueValidator (10.0)]
              )

user = models.ForeignKey (CustomUser, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
movie = models.ForeignKey (Movie, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
created_at = models.DateTimeField (default = datetime.now)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField (auto_now = True)

class Meta:
   unique_together = ('user', 'movie')
    indexes = [
        models.Index(fields=['user', 'movie']),
    ]
```

but first you have to clean the model for  duplicate entries  because  if you migrate you may have errors

for the view you can have smth like this  (not tested)

```
def view_movie_detail (request, movie_id):
movie, created = Movie.objects.get_or_create(id=movie_id)
# if method is post then the form will populated with posted data  else will be empty form 
form = Comment_movie_CreateForm(request.POST or None)
# check if user has comment about that movie
comment_exists = Comment_movie.objects.filter(user=request.user,movie=movie).exists()
if comment_exists:
    # if comment exists return a message to the view html 
    context['message'] = "Dear {} you already commented that movie {}".format(request.user,movie)
    return render (request, "Movie / movie_detail.html", context)
# save the new comment
if form.is_valid():
    Comment_movie (
        comment = form.cleaned_data ['comment'],
        user = request.user,
        stars = form.cleaned_data ['stars'],
        movie = movie
    ).save()
    return redirect('view_movie_detail', movie_id = movie_id)
data = requests.get(f "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{movie_id}?api_key={TMDB_API_KEY}&language=en-US")
recommendations = requests.get(f "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{movie_id}/recommendations?api_key={TMDB_API_KEY}&language=en-US")
comments = reversed(Comment_movie.objects.filter (movie_id = movie_id))
average = movie.average_stars()
context = {
        "data": data.json(),
        "recommendations": recommendations.json(),
        "type": "movie",
        "comments": comments,
        "average": average,
        "form": form,
}
return render (request, "Movie / movie_detail.html", context)
```

Comment: Is it necessary to change Views.py?

Comment: you need to change the clean method  of your model form  to check if user has commented for a specific movie  to return the appropriate validation error message

Comment: Do you mean change fields = ('comment', 'stars','index') and add def clean_index()?

Comment: for form validation in django you can refer to the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/validation/

Comment: Is it possible to add update and delet to this views.py?

Comment: I can't do form validation, can you show me the code?

Comment: If I implement Update and delete from here, how should I implement it? Where should I change?

Comment: you need  one function for the update method  and one function for the delete method

Comment: Is it impossible to do it in one view function?

Comment: We want to use the same URL for create, delete, read, and update as much as possible.

Comment: ok develop it and update your question with the updated code you have

Comment: ok.Please do so in response to that question.

Comment: as i said develop it and update the question with the code you have

Comment: Updated code. Questions have also been updated.

Comment: what html you have for the update method  and the delete method ?

Comment: I forgot to include it, it's in the html as botton.

Comment: ok update then your question with the correct html  , also include the url  pattern you have for the  crud  url